# Search doesn´t work on the front-end

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have just made a search option on my website with ajax, and the data comes from a text file. I handled the search in the PHP api, which does the job, however the problem is on the front-end to display this search result. That doesn´t work for some reason, so I need your help guys?

My search PHP api:

```
<?php

//DATA coming from the browser
$sSearch = $_GET['search'];
//TURN it into UPPERCASE
strtoupper( $sSearch );

//GETTING FROM FILE:
$sajProducts = file_get_contents( 'products.txt' );
$ajProducts = json_decode( $sajProducts );

$matchfound = false;
//LOOPING THROUGH THE ARRAY OF PRODUCTS
for ( $i=0; $i< count( $ajProducts ); $i++ ) {

    if ( $sSearch == $ajProducts[$i]->name ) {
         $jSearchResult = $ajProducts[$i];
         $matchfound = true;    
         break;
    }
}
//if there is a match display the product
if ( $matchfound ) {
    echo json_encode ( $jSearchResult );
    exit;
}
//if not display ALL products
else { 

     echo json_encode( $ajProducts );
     exit;
}

?>
```

My JAVASCRIPT bit:

```
  txtSearchProducts.addEventListener("keyup", function() {

  var sSearch = document.getElementById("txtSearchProducts").value;
  console.log( sSearch );
  var sSearchUpperCase = sSearch.toUpperCase();        
  var sUrl = "api_search_products.php?search=" + sSearchUpperCase;

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if ( this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200 ) { 
           ajProductDataFromServer = JSON.parse( this.responseText );
           console.log( "Response:" + ajProductDataFromServer );



           if ( sessionStorage.getItem('role') === "admin" ) { 

                showProductAdmin();
                console.log ("SEARCH FOUND");

          } else {

                showProduct();
                console.log ("SEARCH FOUND");

          }


      }
  } 

  request.open( "GET", sUrl, true );
  request.send();

});
```

It does consols the ajProductData = a JSON object, and if I stringify it then i can see is the right thing, so it means my serach works, hovewer it does not displays anything on the screen. So I am suspecting the problem could be with the way I try to display that, which is with the ShowProductAdmin(); or Showproduct();
What this contains you can see it next:

```
// DISPLAY PRODUCTS for ADMIN dinamically using a loop and then INSERT into HTML

  function showProductAdmin() {

      lblProductList.innerHTML = "";

      for ( var i = 0; i < ajProductDataFromServer.length; i++ ) {

          var lblProduct = '<div class="lblProduct">' + '<img src="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].image + '"width="85%" alt="product" class="lblProductImage" data-productImage="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].image + '">' + '<h3 class ="lblProductName" data-productName="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].name + '" >' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].name + '</h3>' + '<h3 class ="lblProductPrice" data-productPrice="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].price + '">' + 'Price:' + ' ' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].price + '<h3 class ="lblProductQuantity" data-productQuantity="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].quantity + '">' + 'Quantity:' + ' ' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].quantity + '</h3>' + '<button id="btnEditProductBody" class="btnShowPage btnEditProduct" data-showThisPage="pageUpdateProduct" data-productId="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].id + '">' + 'EDIT PRODUCT' + '</button>' + '<button class="btnDeleteProduct" data-productId="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].id + '" >' + 'DELETE PRODUCT' + '</button>' + '<h3 class="lblErrorMessage" id="lblDeleteProductErrorMessage">' + '</h3>' + '</div>';

          lblProductList.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', lblProduct );
          showPages();

      }

  }



 // DISPLAY PRODUCTS for USER / PUBLIC dinamically using a loop and then INSERT into HTML

  function showProduct() {
      lblProductList.innerHTML = "";

      for ( var i = 0; i < ajProductDataFromServer.length; i++ ) {

          var lblProduct = '<div class ="lblProduct">' + '<img src="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].image + '" width="85%" alt="product">' + '<h3 class ="lblProductName">' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].name + '</h3>' + '<h3 class ="lblProductPrice">' + 'Price:' + ' ' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].price + '<h3 class ="lblProductQuantity">' + 'Quantity:' + ' ' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].quantity + '</h3>' + '<button class="btnBuyProduct" data-productId="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].id + '" >' + 'BUY PRODUCT' + '</button>' + '</div>';

          lblProductList.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', lblProduct );
      }

  }
```

However in other context like when I display all products it works fine:
See an example of here:

```
// GET ALL PRODUCTS and display them with diffrent features according role

  function getajProductData() {

      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if ( this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200 ) {

              ajProductDataFromServer = JSON.parse( this.responseText );
              console.log( "Response:" + ajProductDataFromServer );

              if ( sessionStorage.getItem('role') === "admin" ) { 
                  console.log( "PRODUCTS ARE EDITABLE" );
                  showProductAdmin();

              } else if ( sessionStorage.getItem('role') === "user" ) {
                  console.log( "PRODUCTS ARE AVAILABLE FOR USER" );
                  showProduct();

              } else {
                  console.log( "PRODUCTS AVAILABLE FOR PUBLIC" );
                  showProduct();
              }

          }
      }

      request.open( "GET", "api_get_products.php", true );
      request.send();

  }
```

And the HTML, where I also initialize all the products with the getajProductData();

```
!-- PRODUCTS display and editing is handled here according USER or ADMIN-->

    <div id="pageViewProducts" class="page">
            <div class="lblWrapper"> 
                  <button type="button" class="btnShowPage" id="btnCreateProduct" data-showThisPage="pageCreateProduct"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;Add Product</button>
                  <form id="frmSortBy">
                    <p>Sort by:</p>
                    <select id="sortProductsSelector">
                      <option value="oPriceLowToHigh">PRICE (LOW TO HIGH)</option>
                      <option value="oPriceHighToLow" >PRICE (HIGH TO LOW</option>
                      <option value="oOnSale" id="oOnSale" selected>ON SALE</option>
                    </select>
                  </form>
                  <div id="lblProductList">
                    <!-- Generated dynamically -->
                  </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Could be an interfering there?

My users.txt file:

```
[
    {
        "role": "admin",
        "id": "59df4ef2d8d39",
        "email": "a@a.dk",
        "name": "A",
        "lastname": "A",
        "password": "1",
        "image": "img_webshop\/userimage-59dfb91515810.png"
    },
    {
        "role": "user",
        "id": "59df4f1b070e6",
        "phonenumber": "12345678",
        "name": "B",
        "lastname": "B",
        "password": "2",
        "image": "img_webshop\/userimage-59df8c0317707.png"
    },
    {
        "role": "user",
        "id": "59dfc0cb07985",
        "email": "c@c.dk",
        "name": "C",
        "lastname": "C",
        "password": "3",
        "image": "img_webshop\/userimage-59dfc0cb06c5f.png"
    },
    {
        "role": "user",
        "id": "59dfc22f26f78",
        "phonenumber": "87654321",
        "name": "D",
        "lastname": "D",
        "password": "4",
        "image": "img_webshop\/userimage-59dfc22f2638d.png"
    },
    {
        "role": "user",
        "id": "59dfc460b261e",
        "email": "e@e.dk",
        "name": "E",
        "lastname": "E",
        "password": "5",
        "image": "img_webshop\/userimage-59dfc460af866.png"
    }
]
```

What I search for is the name of each object so if I type A in the searchbar I should see only see the JSON object with the name A, and so on. Normally all the products are displayed as I mentioned before with the getajUserData(); 
I hope it´s understable.

Comment: Any new ideas on how would you convert the result from the api in the javascript to the front-end?

Comment: Can you show the structure of the JSON received from the ajax call or an example of it and an example of your expected - rendered output? Thank you.

Comment: Sure. I just added above.

Answer (score 0):

After research I found out that the problem was actually in the api and due to that wasn´t properly displaying the front end, so now here is the corrected api, which I posted right at the start of the post. Now with correction this the whole full-stack works properly.

```
 <?php

    //DATA coming from the browser
    $sSearch = $_GET['search'];
    //TURN it into UPPERCASE
    strtoupper( $sSearch );

    //GETTING FROM FILE:
    $sajProducts = file_get_contents( 'products.txt' );
    $ajProducts = json_decode( $sajProducts );

    $matchfound = false;
    $jSearchResult = array();
    //LOOPING THROUGH THE ARRAY OF PRODUCTS
    for ( $i=0; $i< count( $ajProducts ); $i++ ) {

        if ( $sSearch == $ajProducts[$i]->name ) {
             $jSearchResult[] = $ajProducts[$i];
             $matchfound = true;    
        }
    }
    //if there is a match display the product
    if ( $matchfound ) {
        echo json_encode ( $jSearchResult );
        exit;
    }
    //if not display ALL products
    else { 

         echo json_encode( $ajProducts );
         exit;
    }

    ?>
```